# Radio button list not binding to view model on post back in mvc core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, radio-group

Here is view component code I am using for loop and only one radio button can be selected from each line.
On Edit view loading it works fine and binding the values to the model but on post back it is not. Please help me on this.  I am not sure how the name or value attributes should be used on radio buttons. But when I am trying to change the name then grouping of each row does not work.

```
@model SecurityFormProfileViewModel

<div id="forms">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Form Name</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SecurityForms.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.SecurityForms[i].FormId" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.SecurityForms[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.SecurityForms[i].IsSelected">@Model.SecurityForms[i].FormName</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="@Model.SecurityForms[i].NoAccess" type="radio" name="@i" id="inlineRaio1" value="@Model.SecurityForms[i].NoAccess"
                                   checked="@Model.SecurityForms[i].NoAccess">
                            <label class="form-check-label">No Access</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="@Model.SecurityForms[i].DisplayOnly" type="radio" name="@i" id="inlineRadio2"  value="@Model.SecurityForms[i].DisplayOnly"
                                   checked="@Model.SecurityForms[i].DisplayOnly">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Display Only</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="@Model.SecurityForms[i].FullAccess" type="radio"  name="@i" id="inlineRadio3" value="@Model.SecurityForms[i].FullAccess"
                                   checked="@Model.SecurityForms[i].FullAccess">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Full Access</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the models?

Comment: I have sorted this by changing my models. There was issue with my models I was binding radio on three properties in my model individually. Then I used the list for these properties and bound to value attribute the added one more property for selectedaccesslevel and bind that property to asp-for and last thing name attribute was causing issue so i removed that one and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, I am glad you can solve the problem :)